# django-sorcery isn't autogenerating migrations

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, django-sorcery

I'm playing around with the [django-sorcery](https://github.com/shosca/django-sorcery) library, and I've been trying to generate some migrations:

```
django-admin sorcery revision -m "Second revision" --autogenerate -v 1 my_app
```

When I first ran the command, I saw an error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: [... snip ...]python3.7/site-packages/django_sorcery/db/alembic/script.py.mako
```

Not sure why the template is missing from the pip package, I added it back in by hand.

Now, the command just generates empty migration files, even though I specify the --autogenerate flag.

Should I be throwing an env.py file somewhere? is this command actually supposed to work yet? Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the missing template was actually resolved in a recent release so would recommend to give that a try.

as for the models not being picked up, couple of ideas which might be useful

- model needs to be a sorcerified model. in order words it needs to subclass `db.Model`:

```py
from django_sorcery.db import databases
db = databases.get("default")
class MyModel(db.Model):
    ...
```

- model needs to be defined inside one of `INSTALLED_APPS`. internally sorcery uses [`get_containing_app_config`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c8720e7696ca41f3262d5369365cc1bd72a216ca/django/apps/registry.py#L243) to get the corresponding django app for a model since sqlalchemy model is not natively registered within a django app
- by default nothing else is required hence no need for a traditional `env.py`. some basic customizations are allowed in apps `AppConfig`:

  - `version_table` - defaults to `alembic_version_{app.label}`
  - `version_table_schema`

  if not sufficient there are couple of [signals](https://github.com/shosca/django-sorcery/blob/master/django_sorcery/db/signals.py#L96-L99) which can be used to hook into alembic config creation for customization

that should make the migration command work. repo ships with a [`test_site`](https://github.com/shosca/django-sorcery/tree/master/test_site) which contains a canonical `polls` app for testing. you can experiment with it and alembic migrations:

```
$ cd test_site
$ ./manage.py sorcery revision -m 'initial migration' -r 0001 --autogenerate polls
$ cat polls/migrations/0001_initial_migration.py
...
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('question',
    sa.Column('pk', sa.Integer(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('question_text', sa.String(length=200), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('pub_date', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('pk')
    )
    op.create_table('choice',
    sa.Column('pk', sa.Integer(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('choice_text', sa.String(length=200), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('votes', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('question_pk', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['question_pk'], ['question.pk'], ),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('pk')
    )
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
...
```

disclaimer: Im one of the maintainers of django-sorcery. thanks for trying it! if you run into any bugs feel free to open issues. lots of stuff is not very well documented yet as we are building out features but hopefully over time docs and stability will improve.

Comment: thanks! I think I had a typo in my INSTALLED_APPS, I'll see if fixing that helps.

Comment: any chance there's an easy way to plug django-sorcery models into django admin? so I can edit tables etc...

Comment: not at this time. I started some work for admin support but its at early stages. eventually hope to get it running https://github.com/shosca/django-sorcery/pull/109